# Download and view podcast

Tags: podcasts, data

If I download a free podcast onto my iTunes and onto my iPhone does it still use data from my contract?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading podcasts to iTunes on your computer and syncing it from there to your iPhone (via cable or WiFi) does not require a 3G/LTE connection, so you should be fine.